# Backing up tab groups, or online tab/session storage

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, software-rec, browser-addons, session-manager

When tab groups for Firefox came out they perfectly suited my workflow, and I often have 5 or 10 groups of tabs for various projects, or sections of projects. Previously I used a session manager but I found tab groups a lot quicker and easier to use.

The problem however is that for various different reasons I've lost my tab groups; so I need some way of making them more persistent.

Ideally I would like to have something along the lines of the way 'Lastpass' or 'Xmarks' syncs the passwords/bookmarks by storing them online, but I doubt such a system exists so I would settle either for any robust and easy to use way to backup and restore either my tab groups or sessions.

I should mention that while I use Firefox, I could easily be convinced to move to Chrome as the tab groups are the only real reason I need to be in FF ( I tried Tab Sugar for Chrome a few months back and didn't like it as much as the FF native support )

**Here's my ideal scenario in case it helps**

1. Easily add a tab to a group or move it to a different group ( this is a right click and a click in FF )
2. When I add a tab to a group it would be either backed up in realtime ( like the way Dropbox works) or on a fairly regular basis so that if I lost all the tab and/or tab groups from the browser they would be recoverable
3. Storage of more than one backup at a time so that I could go back easily to the backup before the issue.
4. Quick and easy restoration
5. Switch groups / sessions quickly and easily
6. I'd really like to have a visual display like the tab groups and one where I could drag the tabs between groups

**sessionstore.bak**
Just to say w.r.t this that I have found it awkward to get the tabs and groups back from sessionstore.bak; and also sessionstore.bak only stores a single backup which is not much good unless you notice the problem before you restart the browser, which is often not the case. So for this reason I would need something better than simply renaming sessionstore.bak, however maybe there's an extension which helps in this regard.

Comment: This would be great -- I really wish Chrome had native support for tab groups.

Comment: For Google Chrome, there's an extension called "Tab Cloud" that synchronizes tab groups across all Chrome installations - I hope there's something similar for Firefox.

Comment: My problem would be solved though if Chrome had tab groups that worked like Firefox's. I'd rather use chrome and I tried Chrome's idea of tab groups twice or three times and got frustrated with them each time. The tab groups of firefox I find to be much better ( unless chrome has done a major overhaul in the last few months )

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Session Manager extension](http://sessionmanager.mozdev.org/) for firefox. It saves everything you open, including tab groups.

Comment: Session manager indeed saves the groups' state.

Comment: According to [this post](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1193167): since quantum, tab groups needed a proper API to be feasible. A user in the discussion lists [addons with the functionality](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1193167#answer-1110443).